serial communication over RS-232 using C on Windows not working
I am trying to write a program that sends and transmits data between my Windows computer and an Arduino UNO R3 connected through USB. It currently transmits in both directions but when I get it back from the Arduino it's not consistently correct. For example, you can see I'm sending the string 123 to the Arduino and the Arduino is meant to send it right back. What I receive is variations of 123. ( 12,1,123,123123,12123, etc).
I was thinking I needed to do something with master/slave protocol but I'm not too sure how to implement that. I'm relatively new to C, how can I fix this problem?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
 
void print_error(const char * context)
{
  printf("print error");
  DWORD error_code = GetLastError();
  char buffer[256];
  DWORD size = FormatMessageA(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK,
    NULL, error_code, MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),
    buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);
  if (size == 0) { buffer[0] = 0; }
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", context, buffer);
}
 
HANDLE open_serial_port(const char * device, uint32_t baud_rate)
{
  printf("open serial port");
  HANDLE port = CreateFile(device, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (port != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Serial port handle: %p\n", (void*)port);
} else {
    printf("Failed to open serial port.\n");
}
// Flush away any bytes previously read or written.
  BOOL success = FlushFileBuffers(port);
  if (!success)
  {
    print_error("Failed to flush serial port");
    CloseHandle(port);
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  }
 
  // Configure read and write operations to time out after 100 ms.
  COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};
  timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
 
  success = SetCommTimeouts(port, &timeouts);
  if (!success)
  {
    print_error("Failed to set serial timeouts");
    CloseHandle(port);
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  }
   // print_error(device);
   // return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 
 
  // Configure the serial port settings.
  DCB dcbSerialParams; //used to be DCB dcbSerialParams = {0}
  dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
  if (!GetCommState(port, &dcbSerialParams))
  {
    print_error("Failed to get serial port state");
    CloseHandle(port);
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  }
  dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = baud_rate;
  dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
  dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
  dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
  dcbSerialParams.fOutxCtsFlow = TRUE; // Enable RTS/CTS flow control
  //dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE; // Use RTS/CTS flow contr
  if (!SetCommState(port, &dcbSerialParams))
  {
    print_error("Failed to set serial port state");
    CloseHandle(port);
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  }
 
  return port;
}
 
int write_to_serial(HANDLE port, const char * data)
{
  printf("write to serial\n");
  DWORD bytes_written;
  if (!WriteFile(port, data, strlen(data), &bytes_written, NULL))
  {
    print_error("Failed to write to serial port");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
 
char* read_from_serial(HANDLE port, char* buffer, DWORD buffer_size)
{
    printf("Read from Serial\n");
    int i = 0;
    DWORD bytes_read;
    char tempChar;
 
    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
 
    do
    {
        if (!ReadFile(port, &tempChar, sizeof(tempChar), &bytes_read, NULL))
        {
            print_error("Failed to read from serial port");
            return NULL; // Return NULL on error
        }
 
        if (bytes_read > 0 && tempChar != '\n')
        {
            buffer[i] = tempChar;
            i++;
        }
    } while (bytes_read > 0 && tempChar != '\n');
 
    // Null-terminate the buffer
    buffer[i] = '\0';
 
    return buffer;
}
 
void clear_serial_port(HANDLE port)
{
    PurgeComm(port, PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
}
 

// int read_from_serial(HANDLE port, char * buffer, DWORD buffer_size)
// {
//   printf("Read from Serial\n");
//   DWORD bytes_read;
//   if (!ReadFile(port, buffer, buffer_size, &bytes_read, NULL))
//   {
//     print_error("Failed to read from serial port");
//     return -1;
//   }
//   return bytes_read;
// }
 
int main()
{
  // Choose the serial port name.
  const char * device = "COM4";
 
  // Choose the baud rate (bits per second).
  uint32_t baud_rate = 9600;
 
  // Open the serial port.
  HANDLE port = open_serial_port(device, baud_rate);
  if (port == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { printf("Invalid handle on COM port"); return 1;}
 
  // Write data to the serial port.
  const char * data = "123\n";
  if (write_to_serial(port, data)) {printf("Failed to write to serial port"); return 1; }
   
  // Read data from the serial port.
  // char buffer[256];
  // int bytes_read = read_from_serial(port, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  // if (bytes_read > 0) {
  //   buffer[bytes_read] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
  //   printf("waiting");
  //   printf("Received data from serial port: %s\n", buffer);
  // }
  // else{printf("No data received");}
 
  // Read data from the serial port.
char buffer[256];
char* received_data = read_from_serial(port, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if (received_data != NULL)
{
    // Print received data
    printf("Received data from serial port: %s\n", received_data);
}
else
{
    printf("No data received or error occurred\n");
}
 
  // Clear the serial port.
  clear_serial_port(port);
 
  // Close the serial port.
  CloseHandle(port);
  printf("Success!\n");
  return 0;
}


Is the arduino sending "123" repeatedly?

Have you tried calling clear_serial_port() before trying to read from it?

No the arduino sends it once only and I also tried clear_serial_port() before read, after write, and also on the Arduino after it was received.

You should post your arduino code as well as the windows code. If the arduino is receiving a string and echoing it back, and the data comes back inconsistent, I'd guess the arduino input is dropping chars. So, we really need to see both sides of the issue. Again, since arduino is relatively slow, the code can be tricky to get right.

"serial communication over RS-232 ,,, through USB" - Your hardware connection is contradictory. The only code you show us the Windows side; what does the Arduino side do? "What I receive is variations of 123 ..." - You're using an asynchronous serial link (with ill-defined HW) that only frames each byte/character over the wire. There is no framing of messages or lines; that's a job the software (i.e. a protocol layer) has to resolve. So you cannot expect to receive nice tidy lines unless you explicitly configure both ends of the serial link to perform canonical processing.

"// Configure read and write operations to time out after 100 ms." - A simple debugging step to always try is to extend (short) timeouts to absurd values. IOW increase this timeout to 5000ms. Then verify that program progress messages (e.g. write to serial and Received data from serial port: ...  match the increased delay.

@user25047058 Tip: Use sentinels to better detect white-space in uncontrolled strings: fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", context, buffer); --> fprintf(stderr, "%s: <%s>\n", context, buffer);
